# Semantic Type Safety in Python

Tags: python, types, type-safety

In my recent project I have the problem, that some values are often misinterpreted. For instance I calculate a wave as a sum of two waves (for which I need two amplitudes and two phase shifts), and then sample it at 4 points. I pass these tuples of four values to different functions, but sometimes I made the mistake to pass wave parameters instead of sample points.

These errors are hard to find, because all the calculations work without any error, but the values are totally meaningless in this context and so the results are just wrong.

What I want now is some kind of semantic type. I want to state that the one function returns sample points and the other function awaits sample points, and that I can do nothing that would conflict this declarations without immediately getting an error.

Is there any way to do this in python?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a left-typed language. When you pass wrong parameters around, the compiler/interpreter not necessarily will be able to spot this behaviour, even with parameter types. Imagine that point are tuples of floats, and a wave is also a tuple of floats (amplitude and phase)...

Comment: Python enforce Duck Typing ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing ) which is contrary to compile-time type safety. You can find a workaround (look at __class__ for example), but I would suggest you to use C function whenever you need type check (Python has close connexions with C).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend implementing specific data types to be able to distinguish between different kind of information with the same structure.
You can simply subclass `list` for example and then do some type checking at runtime within your functions:

```
class WaveParameter(list):
    pass

class Point(list):
    pass

# you can use them just like lists    
point = Point([1, 2, 3, 4])

wp = WaveParameter([5, 6])

# of course all methods from list are inherited
wp.append(7)
wp.append(8)

# let's check them
print(point)
print(wp)

# type checking examples
print isinstance(point, Point)
print isinstance(wp, Point)
print isinstance(point, WaveParameter)
print isinstance(wp, WaveParameter)
```

So you can include this kind of type checking in your functions, to make sure the correct kind of data was passed to it:

```
def example_function_with_waveparameter(data):
    if not isinstance(data, WaveParameter):
        log.error("received wrong parameter type (%s instead WaveParameter)" %
                  type(data))
    # and then do the stuff
```

or simply `assert`:

```
def example_function_with_waveparameter(data):
    assert(isinstance(data, WaveParameter))
```

Comment: OP: "conflict this declarations". He is talking about typed parameters in the declaration of a function.

Comment: Such hard-coded typechecking is not pythonic - and it won't do what the OP asks for.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes of course, you're right, it does not do what the OP asks for and of course it's not "pythonic", but it's one possible solution. Of course an overall redesign of his code would be the best way (probably introducing hard refactoring): moving the logic to class methods for example…

Comment: Well, it is not as nice, as I wished, but I get get error messages with little extra code, so I will try it.

Answer (score 2):

Pyhon's notion of a "semantic type" is called a `class`, but as mentioned, Python is dynamically typed so even using custom classes instead of tuples you won't get any compile-time error - at best you'll get runtime errors if your classes are designed in such a way that trying to use one instead of the other will fail.

Now classes are not just about data, they are about behaviour too, so if you have functions that do waveform-specific computations these functions would probably become methods of the `Waveform` class, and idem for the `Point` part, and this might be enough to avoid logical errors like passing a "waveform" tuple to a function expecting a "point" tuple.

To make a long story short: if you want a statically typed functional language, Python is not the right tool (Haskell might be a better choice). If you really want / have to use Python, try using classes and methods instead of tuples and functions, it still won't detect type errors at compile-time but chances are you'll have less type errors AND that these type errors will be detected at runtime instead of producing wrong results.

Comment: Using methods instead of functions we require a somewhat bigger change in my whole source code, but I agree, that it might be a better way.

Comment: @JonathanK: with unittests and a bit of introspection you can refactor your code base without too much of a "big bang" effect. But yes, it can indeed be a somewhat involved refactoring depending on your code base size and complexity. It will still make for less work than porting to another language...